# Change UI RectTransform position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

I have these lines :

```
GameObject bp = Instantiate(MyPrefab);
bp.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ContentFactory").transform);
bp.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
```

Si, I just instantiate a prefab, I set a parent and I want to change the position.

My problem is, the function `SetParent` set a fixed position to my `bp` GameObject, and after that I don't know how to change this position. The last line change nothing.... The same with `.position`.

How can I change the position of `bp` ? Thanks !

Edit :

Inspector of ContentFactory :

[image]

Inspector of a bp :

[image]

Hierarchy (Content in blue is ContentFactory) :

[image]

Comment: So, when you make an object a child of another object, localPosition = (0,0,0) is the same point in space as where that parent exists. If that parent exists at (0,0,0) in scene space (assuming it is not itself a child), then position = (0,0,0) would be identical. I'm not sure what your problem is, it works for me.

Comment: Aaah, we're dealing with *`RectTransform`s*.  Changing a RectTransform's anchors and pivot muck about with its effective position. Are you changing its anchors at all anywhere?

Comment: No, I don't change anchor anywhere

Comment: Well, for a scroll view, you generally want the anchor min:max to be `(0,1):(0,1)` not `(0.5,0.5):(0.5,0.5)` so that the `localPosition` value actually means something, or do as Programmer suggests and use `RectTransform.anchoredPosition`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `transform.localPosition` will use it relative position. If you want to change the position in world space, you need to use `transform.position`.

```
GameObject bp = Instantiate(MyPrefab);
bp.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ContentFactory").transform);
bp.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
```

**EDIT:**

This is a UI Object with a `RectTransform`. You shouldn't move it with transform.position.

It should be moved with:

`bp.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = ...`

or

`bp.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D = ...`

Note that there are other things that play role when using `RectTransform`.

This includes `anchorMax` and `anchorMin` which can be modified with:

```
bp.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMax = ...
bp.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMin = ...
```

Comment: According to his question, using `position` instead didn't change anything: *"The last line change nothing.... The same with `.position`."* But I do agree that that *should* be the thing he's looking for.

Comment: @Draco18s Just noticed that.

Comment: @ClémentAndraud Are you moving ContentFactory(parent object) anywhere? If so then, it should also change the child position. Please verify that you are not moving the parent object.

Comment: And can you show a picture of the inspector after the code runs, showing the object's position?

Comment: ContentFactory is not moving.

Comment: Ok. Do what Draco said. Update your question with the screenshot of the hierarchy where the bp is when instantiated.

Comment: You only uploaded the inspector. That's fine but please upload the hierarchy too.

Comment: I don't understand why ^^ I do exactly the same thing in another Panel (BuildingPanel), and setParent with .transform.localPosition work.

Comment: I noticed that you should not move UI with `transform.position` or `transform.localPosition` in Unity. It may work sometimes but those variable are reserved for Objects without `RectTransform`. For Example, Cube with `MeshRenderer` or Sprite with `SpriteRenderer`. My edited answer should work for you. Where exact do you want to position the bp(child) Object?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to supply a different answer than Programmer did, just because it's how I handle my dynamically filled ScrollViews with the new UI system. I will have to play around to see if using `RectTransform.anchoredPosition` instead works better or not.

---

I set the anchor min:max values to `(0,1):(0,1)` so that the buttons (images, text, whatever) treats the top-left corner of the scroll view as the origin.  Then I set the pivot to be `(0,1)` as well, so that the top left corner of the button is the origin (and then these values are baked into the prefab: I never need to fiddle with them again).  This lets me set the position to `(0,0,0)` and have it be placed where I want it to be, although I'll generally nudge them right and down by a few pixels so that it Looks Nice, but all of the items receive the same flat offsets.

[image: RectTransform settings]

Then [in my code I can use `.localPosition`](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/game/CraftingManager.cs#L37) in a manner that allows those values to line up with where I expect my object to be placed, keeping in mind that new items need to be added below the old items, therefor each button's Y value is going to be negative after the first one.  This offset will be equal to the item's height (visible in the Inspector) plus a few pixels for padding.

Finally, I always make sure to call `SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Vertical, totalHeight)` on the ScrollView's content's RectTransform to update the scrollbars to the proper values, and if necessary, to reset the content transform's own position to `(0,0,0)` so that it is scrolled back to the top. `totalHeight` is effectively the (positive) Y position of the next item that *would* be placed, plus another flat buffer amount (same value used to offset things from the top) again, so it Looks Nice.